# Validate pressed button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am developing a "game" like Simons Says. I have seven sounds in a Jframe

[image]

I need to reproduce for example the "Do" note, then the user has to press the same note. After the app has to reproduce the "Do" note and then "Re", and the user has to press the same notes in that order.
So I have created a start button, and the first sound will be reproduced some seconds after...
My doubt is how can i validate that the button pressed by the user is the button that has sounded?

This is  the code for the  Start button:

```
    private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        //delay the sound
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        sonido("do");
        //mark the border of the played sound
        jButton1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255), 3, true));
        //show in a label the name of the played sound
        jLabel1.setText("DO");
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is the code for  the "do" button (all the others buttons are  the same just change the parameter in the sonido method)

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    setButtonstoNull();
    if(evt.getSource()==jButton1){
        try {
            sonido("do");
            jButton1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255), 3, true));

        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I compare it? If There is a way this comparison should be in the Start button method?

If someone can guide me, very thankful

Comment: Generate a `List` of sounds (or names which represent the sounds, maybe using `enum`s), play this list.  When the use clicks a button, check to see if the button matches the expected sound.  What I would do is actually have a "player" `List`, which is a copy of the original "play" `List`, as the user makes correct guesses,  would remove the first element from the `List`, this way, you are always just checking the first element, as soon as they make a wrong guess, you can clear this `List` and replay the original "play" `List` and start again

Comment: The list seems a great idea  I will try, thank you for you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an enum like that:

```
public enum Note {
DO
{
    @Override
    public String getNote() {return "do";}
    @Override
    public String getText() {return "DO";}
    @Override
    public Color getColor() {return new Color(255, 255, 255);}
},
RE
{...},
...
SI
{...};

 abstract String getNote()
 abstract String getText()
 abstract String getColor()
}
```

You can use it anywhere to perform comparisons and save some copy/paste.